# Why does my application crash?

Tags: android

I am new to android, and am learning about tasks.  I found this example in a tutorial on using runnable.

```
public class ThreadExample extends Activity {

    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
            String ReturnedInt = Integer.toString(msg.what);
            myTextView.setText(ReturnedInt);

            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(1500);   // Vibrate for 1500 milliseconds
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_thread_example);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.thread_example, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void buttonClick(View view)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 2*1000;
                while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        try {
                            wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                        }   
                        }
                }
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1234);    
            }
        };
        Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
        mythread.start();
    }
}
```

This code works.  If I press the button on the screen, the text box reads "1234" and the vibrator vibrates.  I wanted to rearrange the code a bit, to meet my ultimate goal of writing an audio recorder, where the audio sampling would be in the thread.    I rearranged the code by moving the runnable and thread declarations to the top of the class, so I could reference them from other methods

```
public class ThreadExample extends Activity {

    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
            String ReturnedInt = Integer.toString(msg.what);
            myTextView.setText(ReturnedInt);

            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(1500);   // Vibrate for 1500 milliseconds
        }
    };

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 2*1000;
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                    }   
                    }
            }
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(1234);    
        }
    };
    Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_thread_example);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.thread_example, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void buttonClick(View view)
    {
        mythread.start();
    }
}
```

If a run the application again, is works the first time i press the button, the text is updated and the vibrator vibrates, but the second time I press the button the program crashes.  I think it may be something to do with the thread being destroyed, but I thought the declarations at the start of the class would not be destroyed until the class was destroyed.  It may be something else.

Any Ideas why it crashes the second time I hit the button?

Edit - As requested, here is the logcat output

```
08-11 09:49:37.489: W/dalvikvm(5014): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8560)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2168)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2552)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9229)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2163)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     ... 11 more
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1227)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     at com.example.threadexample.ThreadExample.buttonClick(ThreadExample.java:60)
08-11 09:49:37.509: E/AndroidRuntime(5014):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: I did not dig through the code, but have you looked for potential Logcat insights? A very interesting detail would be the exception/error.

Comment: yes he's right.. would narrow it down

Comment: You could even add the logcat here and we can help you decipher it

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.` You're trying to start a thread you've already started.  Maybe you're clicking the button twice?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic understanding of the stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the main cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1227)
    at com.example.threadexample.ThreadExample.buttonClick(ThreadExample.java:60)
```

You cannot reuse the same `Thread` object. You have to create a new `Thread` object before you call `.start()` again.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29):

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

Comment: Thanks.  I really appreciate it.  As I say I am new to android, and its a bit overwhelming.  Too much to learn at once.